# Basement bath: Can I tie a wet bar sink into bathroom vanity drain?

Tags: bathroom, drain, sink, vent

I've seen similar questions asked, but there seem to be enough variables that I'd like to ask here to be sure. See attached photos. I have a basement bath roughed in, it is wet vented. The vanity is the most downstream fixture. On the other side of the bathroom wall, I'd like to put a bar sink, and I'd like to run the drain line through the wall, through the bath vanity cabinet, and tie it into the vanity drain line.

Is this permitted? If so, is there a maximum distance between the two sinks and/or a minimum height for the bar sink? Do I have to vent the bar sink separately, and if so, can I use a studor vent? I am in Indiana.

I don't want to do this badly enough to dig into the concrete floor to access the drain line, so if there is no good solution, I'd rather just forget about it. However, if there IS a good solution, I'd rather do it now than down the road.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

[image: wetbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you put a T into vertical line, not jump on the horizontal drain line you are all good.   There really isn't much else to say.   We do this all the time with double vanity sinks.

Comment: Appreciated. Does it matter whether the new T is above or below the existing one?

Comment: Nah, doesn't matter.  I would tend to want to slope it more.   Bigger question... you are going to move that vent right?

Comment: The return air? Haven't decided how to handle that yet. May just build a wet bar that's open underneath.

Comment: You want to make sure that where the wet bar drain ties into the vertical pipe is above the bottom of the wet bar's j-trap.  From your picture looks like this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If it is return air I would just move it.